# Google Analytics Tracking- Split dynamically

Tags: email, google-analytics, tracking

We are looking to track a payment link - which is located in a button in an email. We currently have the tracking set up for the email which is pulling through fine but we are hoping to be able to further segment.

We would like to be able to see where they came from, so out of the people who clicked this link how many were from an Agent and how many from direct customers (this is salesforce data) however still using the same link for everyone rather than having to create different emails.

Members of my team seem to think there is a way of dynamically splitting the tracking code, however, have no idea how. This may not make sense or even be possible, but thought it was worth a shot.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Katy :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related

Answer (score 0):

If your email system can insert personalized parameters into the link based on the user type in your SF data, then you could use [campaign parameters](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) - this would allow you to use the same url for all users, but still have different groups based on campaign attribution.

You should have your email links tagged in any case, so you could use medium/source/campaign as usual and use the optional content parameter to discern between agents and customers:

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Winternewsletter2018&utm_content=agent
```

Then you could create segments or audiences based on the value for utm_content.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful!